# Javascript and PHP for each loop to output an array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am trying to create a javascript array using content that is pulled from a php database.

```
<?php

//This creates an array from the database and allows us to use it later in the jquery
//CREATE SQL STATEMENT
$sql_locations = "SELECT * FROM tbllocations";

//CONNECT TO MYSQL SERVER
require('test-connection.php');
//EXECUTE SQL STATEMENT
$rs_locations = mysqli_query($vconnection, $sql_locations);
$rs_locations_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_locations);

foreach( $rs_locations as $rs_location ) {
  $markers[] = array(
      "{$rs_location['place']}, {$rs_location['city']}",
     $rs_location['long'],
      $rs_location['lat']
  );
}
?>
<div id="map_wrapper">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
</div>


<style>

    #map_wrapper {
        height: 400px;
    }

    #map_canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }


</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>

    function initialize() {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: "roadmap",
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.608941, -122.340145), // somewhere in the uk BEWARE center is required
            zoom: 3,
        };

        // Display a map on the page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);

        // Multiple Markers
        var markers = <?php echo json_encode( $markers ); ?>;

        // Info Window Content
        var infoWindowContent = [

            <?php while($rs_location_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_location)) { ?>

            ['<div class="info_content">' +

            '<h3><?php echo $rs_locations_rows['branch']; ?></h3>' +

            '<p><?php echo $rs_locations_rows['content']; ?></p>' + 

            '<p><?php echo $rs_locations_rows['phone']; ?></p>' + 

            '</div>']

            <?php } ?>


        ];

        // Display multiple markers on a map
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;

        // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });

            // Allow each marker to have an info window
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

        //Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
            this.setZoom(10);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>
```

I have updated the code to show my whole page. I have tried this while loop in the meantime and adding that in stops my page from generating and outputting my map, so my page will hang.

I am thinking to do a for each loop the same way that I have done for the markers, but I have not succeeded thus far

Comment: Show the code that didn't work as expected.

Comment: Rather than trying to fill in a literal, why not create your data structure in php and then use a JSON method to create the literal

Comment: please explain the JSON literal theory? Do you know of any docs?

Comment: Change the `do ... while` to a `while` the first time through a `do..while` there will be no data in `$rs_location_rows` unless you read the first row before starting the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are basically trying to build a string containing some js code and then pass it directly to the browser, I would build a string in PHP and then echo the lot in one go. Its easier to see what you are doing.

```
<?php
$js = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$js .= 'var infoWindowContent = [';

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_location)) { 

    $js .= "['" . '<div class="info_content">';
    $js .= "<h3>{$row['branch']}</h3>";
    $js .= "<p>{$row['content']}</p>";
    $js .= "<p>{$row['phone']}</p>";    
    $js .= "</div>'],";    
}

// trim off the js interpreter breaking trailing comma
$js = rtrim( $js, ',' );

// close the outer array
$js .= '];';
$js .= '</script>';

echo $js;
?>
```

Comment: This is the closest that I have gotten. Thank you, I can now atleast see errors in my console, and can debug from there

Comment: I think it is me, not you, I get "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result", So need to look at my sql

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the `do` `while` structure to `while`:
As also mentioned by @RiggsFolly. (sorry I see now)

```
var infoWindowContent = [

    <?php while($rs_location_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_location)) { ?>

    ['<div class="info_content">' +

    '<h3><?php echo $rs_locations_rows['branch']; ?></h3>' +

    '<p><?php echo $rs_locations_rows['content']; ?></p>' + 

    '<p><?php echo $rs_locations_rows['phone']; ?></p>' + 

    '</div>'],

    <?php } ?>

];
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry did not see your comment, credits to you

Comment: This does not seem to work either. It hangs on a the page. Do you know of any other methods I could attempt?

Comment: That your page hangs does not need to be caused by this? Give more content to see where your error could be located. Or try to reproduce a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach i would use to do that:

```
var myArray = [
    <?php while ($rs_location_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_location)) : ?>
    {
        'branch' : '<?= $rs_locations_rows["branch"] ?>',
        'content' : '<?= $rs_locations_rows["content"] ?>',
        'phone' : '<?= $rs_locations_rows["phone"] ?>'
    },
    <?php endwhile; ?>
];
console.log(myArray);
```

Now you have the array in your js.

Comment: But that does not pass the HTML as part of what you are sending to the browser, so you will also have to show him how to take your js array of objects and write js to dynamically build the HTML he wants it wrapped in. You also need to work out how to remove the compiler breaking trailing comma after the last array occurance

Comment: Just tested. With the array of objects you can easly make a script to generate the html. I like to separate the processes so it will be easy to change the code later. As i said, thats the way i would use :P